# How to handle Command 'extension.commandName' not found error in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

The problem occurs when one of the long running command is forcefully killed by **process.kill**

After that whenever I try to execute a command it raise  **Command 'extension.commandName' not found** error.

**Note:** All the commands are properly registered in **package.json** under ***contribution>>command***. Commands are also included as part of **activationEvents**. **Keybinding** also in place for the registered command. I have also checked similar issues [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534068/command-not-found-in-vscode-extension) this but that did not cover my scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I am handling this right now is by exposing another command that fires **workbench.action.reloadWindow**. Once the window is reloaded the extension able to handle request again.